# Android Creating a Grid

Tags: java, android

Is there an Android Library for creating Grid Views similar to the one in [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alarex.gred)

I have done a few google searches but can't seem to be able to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is not grid but graph views. Graph views let you create nodes, linked by lines / arrows.

A while back I used a java Graph library called JGraph, but it's probably not compatible with the android views.

Most answers on this type of question is to use custom views.

Answer (score 1):

not quite sure what you are exactly looking for, but have you checked [Google Charts Visualization](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples) ?